# unable to get the data from the database?

Tags: php, android

When I run my application it always giving me "invalid ip", unable to get the data from the database.
I am a newbie so i dont know much about android.
I get this code from google

following is my snippet code, please help me out.

```
    public class EnterGeneralDetails extends Activity {

    InputStream is=null;
    String result=null;
    String line=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_general_details);

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://thecapitalcitychurch.16mb.com/new/CohortName.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("Pass 1", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("Pass 2", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }

        try
        {
            JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json= null;
            final String[] str1 = new String[JA.length()];
            final String[] str2 = new String[JA.length()];

            for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
            {
                json=JA.getJSONObject(i);
                str1[i] = json.getString("ID");
                str2[i]=json.getString("Cohort_Name");
            }

            final Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner22);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i=0;i<str2.length;i++)
            {
                list.add(str2[i]);
            }


            Collections.sort(list);

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            sp.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
            {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long id)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String item=sp.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Log.e("Item",item);
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
    $DB_USER='u868549735_rj';
    $DB_PASS='myself00';
    $DB_HOST='mysql.hostinger.in';
    $DB_NAME='u868549735_db';
    $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }       

    $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $sql="SELECT ID, Cohort_Name FROM Cohorts";
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
    while($e=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $output[]=$e;
    }   

    print(json_encode($output));
    $mysqli->close();   

    ?>
```

Comment: did you get  this output   `connection success` on log???

Comment: I have visited the site 

http://thecapitalcitychurch.16mb.com/new/CohortName.php


And it shows that it has blocked my ip and goes for some verification. And that process is not responding too. So the problem lies with your server. Change your host where you put your `CohortName.php`

Comment: Look at your logcat. What's the output for `Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());`? Probably a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: As @ZahanSafallwa has pointed out this has nothing to do with your android code, the problem lies purely on the server side. YOur android code does not connect to the database, your PHP script does. Test it in isolation using the browser, either on your desktop or on your phone.

Comment: As i can see...you should use async Task... that is networkOnMainThread Exception.

Comment: and i think it is showing invalid IP cuz you have set the Invalid Ip hard coded in toast in Exception and you have used the super class Exception...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you've got a [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). This occurs when you try to execute any network operation on the main thread.

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness.

To resolve this, take a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

> ```
> private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
>      protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
>          int count = urls.length;
>          long totalSize = 0;
>          for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
>              totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
>              publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
>              // Escape early if cancel() is called
>              if (isCancelled()) break;
>          }
>          return totalSize;
>      }
>
>      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
>          setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
>      }
>
>      protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
>          showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
>      }
>  }
> ```
>
> Once created, a task is executed very simply:
>
> `new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);`

PS:
Using `Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());` is considered bad practice. Use e.printStackTrace() instead.